# Dynamic columns Binding Asp.net MVC with Telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I have a model like this

```
public class product 
{ 
  int ProductId {get;set;} 
  List<attributes> attributes {get;set;} 
} 

public class attributes 
{ 
    public string Data Type{get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;} 
}
```

I want to product model to a MVC grid The attributes  are the columns and number of attributes and datatypes getting only runtime.

Anyone have any idea? Please let me know ....

Comment: Is this Kendo UI with MVC Wrapper or Telerik MVC Extension (discontinued)?

Comment: Telerik MVC Extension (discontinued) only

Comment: Still not get any answers but me fix that ..

Answer (score 0):

Get The count of Attribute and write a for look like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < (Selected.Selected.Count()); i++)
    {
        string columnName = Selected.Selected[i].Name;
        columns.Template(m => m.Getvalue(columnName)).Title(columnName);
    }
```

in model write a method with return
       public string Getvalue(string columnName)
         {
           return  " "+  Value +// what ever u need to show on grid make here
         }